# Can I use Play 2.1 Template Editor and autocomplete for HTML?

Tags: eclipse, playframework

Is there any way to use the Template Editor and some HTML editor at the same time? I would like features like autocomplete for HTML in the Template Editor, or even CSS autocomplete. 
I am currently with the Scala IDE Eclipse 3.7.2.

PS1: I am a very beginner in Play/Scala, but I decided to install Aptana (from update site) for the very small but comfortable niceties it provides, so, dropped the play template editor for a moment. Aptana has also a coffeescript editor so, it helps while I am studying backbone with cofeescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed in this release of Play plugin for the Scala Eclipse IDE:

http://scala-ide.org/blog/play-0.4.0-announcement.html

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ Idea with scala and play2 plugins works fine for me, autocomplete even for routes file.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried really hard to use Intellij 12 or 13 on Ubuntu, got some problems, like Scala facet or performance and memory usage, and gave up, will try again after the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Scala IDE but I know Guillaume Bort, the creator of PlayFramework, has created a [Sublime Text 2 plugin](https://github.com/guillaumebort/play2-sublimetext2) for Playframework. It has autocompletion on most file types.